# Draw Hasse diagram by given partial order task

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, graph-theory

My task is to draw Hasse diagram. I have "$|$" relation, which means divide. The relation is defined by partial order $D = \{ 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 10, 15, 30 \}$ including divisors to number $30$.

My Logic:

I would draw a straight chain line from $1$ to $30$, because all of numbers are divisors to $30$. Does my logic correct? If not why, and how must looks like Hasse diagram?

Comment: No it is not, because, for example, 2 doesn't divide 3, and 3 doesn't divide 2. This means that the poset (actually a lattice) is not a chain.

Comment: Check also [this example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor#Examples); its similar.

Comment: You may also notice that, in the example given in the link above (divisors of 60), the poset of divisors of 30 is a subposet, given by all the elements below 30. That will be the complete answer to your question.

Comment: Is it correct if I say that my Hasse diagram looks like this: rows from bottom to top: row1 - 1, row2 - 2,3,5 row3 - 6,10,15, row 4 - 30. Making connections likes cube like here https://imgur.com/a/KJzvy

Comment: That's correct!

Comment: @amrsa if that is correct please add your comment as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a similar Hasse diagram in the example [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor#Examples).
In this case, it's the lattice of divisors of $60$, under the same order relation (notice this posets are always lattices, under the operations $\gcd$—greatest common divisor—and $\mathrm{lcm}$—least common multiple).
In the case of $30$, it's a square-free number (not divisible by $n^2$, for any $n$); in particular, it's not divisible by $4$, and that's the difference between the diagram of $D_{30}$ and the one of $D_{60}$.
More to the point, $D_{30}$ is the diagram given by all the elements below $30$, in the diagram of $D_{60}$ in the link above.

As an aside, the diagram of $D_n$ is a chain, as you were implying, iff $n = m^k$, for some integer $m$ and positive integer $k$.
As another aside, in the case of $D_{30}$, it is a Boolean lattice, because $30$ is square-free. It can be made into a Boolean algebra by defining the complement $n' = 30/n$.